# Inner classes inheritance and access to enclosing class methods/fields

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

Here are two statements I found concerning inner classes

JavaDocs:

> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated
>   with an instance of its enclosing class and has **direct access to that
>   object's methods and fields**. Also, because an inner class is
>   associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members
>   itself.

On another site I found this:

> A nested class, for the most part, is just that—a class declared in
>   the definition of an enclosing class. **It does not inherit anything
>   from the enclosing class**, and an instance of the nested class cannot
>   be assigned to a variable reference to the enclosing class.

Aren't the bold marked lines contradicting?
How can you not inherit a surrounding objects fields and methods and at the same time have access to its fields and methods?

Comment: inheriting and access are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not see the terms *nested class* and *inner class* as an opposite or something similar. In fact, a [nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) simply describes all sorts of classes that are declared inside another class:

1. Nested classes that are declared static are simply called *static nested classes*.
2. Non-static nested classes are called *inner classes*. There are three types of them (see [JLS §8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) for more info):

   1. A non-static member class.
   2. A local class.
   3. An anonymous class.

The first paragraph you quoted explains that an inner class has access (read: access, not inherit) to the methods and fields of the enclosing *instance*. Note, it is about an instance, not the class.

The second paragraph tries to explain that there is no relationship between a class and a nested class inside it, except for their locations.

Answer (score 4):

No, they do not conflict. Look at the following example:

```
public class A {

     public void foo() {
         //some code
     }

     public class B {

         public void bar() {
              foo();
         }
     }
}
```

In this example, the innerclass `B` can access the method of `A` (or any of its' fields, actually), but in no way does inheritance takes place.

For instance, the following change to `B` would result in a compilation error:

```
 public class B {

     public void bar() {
          super.foo();
     }
 }
```

Because `B` does not inherit from `A`. It can *access* its' instance members, but it does **not** *extend* (inherit) from it.